# Is database back up size is same as database size

Tags: postgresql

am working with PostgreSQL i checked following command then it returns 12MB

```
SELECT pg_size_pretty(pg_database_size('itcs'));
```

but when i took back up using pgadmin back up size is 1MB why this difrence

Comment: [PostgreSQL Backup and restore, sizes are different](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/102077/postgresql-backup-and-restore-sizes-are-different)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are taking a logical backup (with `pg_dump`), the backup contains only the data, no empty pages, no old versions of rows, no padding, no indexes. It may also be compressed. All that can greatly reduce the size.

If you are taking a physical backup, the backup more or less consists of the actual database files as they are, plus recovery logs to get them to a consistent state. So that would be roughly the same size as the database itself (but you can also compress it).

Comment: when i clicks vacuum db size is reducing ,when i want to use vacuum it make any performance issue ?

Comment: You need to vacuum regularly to ensure a good database performance. While the database is in the process of being vacuumed, it may be a bit slow, so you should do this during times of low usage (same goes for taking backups).